# How do you set up a widget to swipe in kivy?

Tags: button, kivy

I would like to incorporate a swiping action on buttons instead of a click on_release event in Kivy.  Does anyone know how to set this up?  I've searched and couldn't find any documentation or examples on this.  I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to make this possible.  Here is an example of how I set up my button but would like for the on touch action to be via swipe:

```
Button
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: rgba('#ffffff')
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    name: 'Page 2'
    color: rgba('#000000')
    font_size: mtx.sp(14)
    size_hint: (1, None)
    height: 70
    on_release: 
        scrn_mngr.current = 'next_screen'
        scrn_mngr.transition.direction = "left"
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Do you mean a swipe like button press -> move mouse (swipe) -> button release? Or a swipe that is just a mouse motion?

Comment: There isn't a swipe mixin as it stands. The solution is to write code to do what you want in the `on_touch_down`, `on_touch_move`, and `on_touch_up` methods. You could make this a mixin class for reusability, and even see about contributing it back to Kivy itself.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your reply.  This would be for a mobile app swipe motion.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Inclement.  I will see what I can do with writing it but I will admit, I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: Check out `swipetodelete` lib for Kivy, I think this is what you are looking for.